# Today's reputation not in history

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

An odd thing has happened today: somehow I've gained +20 reputation (from 519 to 539), yet I don't see what this increase is for. As you can see on the attached screenshot, the last two reputation changes do sum up to +20, but they happened one and two days ago, not today.

I didn't answer any questions, just left a couple of comments. I've also signed in in meta, which added +100 (also not displayed in the history, by the way), but that was only after I saw the discrepancy with +20.

Is it a bug in history reporting, or maybe I'm missing something?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you just get another 100 rep in the last 5 minutes?

Comment: That was for signing in to meta for the first time ("combine accounts for several websites" or something like that). BTW this +100 isn't reflected in the history, too - neither on SO, nor on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

The daily totals are cached for 5 minutes (previously 10), so there may be a delay in today showing up if you visited your profile before the changes happened.